# LWJGL - Game crashes after glEnableVertexAttribArray(1)

Tags: opengl, crash, lwjgl, vertex, pong

I'm trying to create a Pong game in LWJGL . I've managed to draw the "bat" and the ball and I can also make the bat move up and down using W and S keys .

Now I'm trying to color the bat using shaders , but I've encountered an error when I'm trying to - glEnableVertexAttribArray(1) - enable the second vertex array (in the loop) that contains the color. The second vertex array gets enabled , but the game crashes when it attempts to draw my bat - glDrawElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, bat.getIndicesCount(), GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0).

If I delete glEnableVertexAttribArray(1) it draws the bat and somehow colors my bat with the color RED . I tried to modify the color information in the Batt class , but nothing happens , so I'm not sure from where it gets the color .

P.S : I'm running an Arch Linux x64 system .

The fatal error is this one :

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x000000004027ef4b, pid=7664, tid=139636374128384
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (7.0_51-b31) (build 1.7.0_51-b31)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (24.51-b03 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x000000004027ef4b
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/borg/workspace/LWJGL-Test/hs_err_pid7664.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions on how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   http://icedtea.classpath.org/bugzilla
```

The file that contains the rest of the error is this one (I put it in a pastebin link to make it easier to read )  http://pastebin.com/hSnJuAar

Now for the program itself .

Main class :

```
package myPackage;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import myPackage.Bat;
import myPackage.Ball;

import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.*;

public class Test {

    // Setup variables
    private int WIDTH = 800;
    private int HEIGHT = 600;
    private String title = "PONG GAME";

    private  Bat bat;
    private Ball ball;

    //Shader variables
    private int vsId = 0;
    private int fsId = 0;
    private int pId = 0;


    public Test() {

        // Initialize
        System.out.println("-->Initializing OpenGL<--");
        setupOpenGL();
        System.out.println("OpenGL initialized");

        System.out.println("-->Preparing to draw ...<--");
        setupDraw();
        setupShaders();
        System.out.println("...Everything is initialized...");
        System.out.println("Entering loop ...");
        while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {

            loop();

            Display.update();
            Display.sync(60);

        }
        System.out.println("--> EXITING LOOP ");
        System.out.println("-->Cleaning memory<--");
        destroyOpenGL();

    }

    public void setupOpenGL() {

        try {

            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT)); // Create
            // the
            // display
            Display.setTitle(title);
            Display.create();
            System.out.println("Display created");

        } catch (LWJGLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1); // If error , exit program
        }

        GL11.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // Clears the screen with
        // black color

    }

    public void setupDraw() {

        bat = new Bat(-1f,0.3f,0,1,0.07f,0.6f);
        ball = new Ball(0.03f,0,0);

    }

    private void setupShaders() {

        // Load the vertex shader
        vsId = loadShader("/home/borg/workspace/LWJGL-Test/src/myPackage/vertex.glsl", GL20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        // Load the fragment shader
        fsId = loadShader("/home/borg/workspace/LWJGL-Test/src/myPackage/fragment.glsl", GL20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

        // Create a new shader program that links both shaders
        pId = GL20.glCreateProgram();
        GL20.glAttachShader(pId, vsId);
        GL20.glAttachShader(pId, fsId);

        // Position information will be attribute 0
        GL20.glBindAttribLocation(pId, 0, "in_Position");
        // Color information will be attribute 1
        GL20.glBindAttribLocation(pId, 1, "in_Color");

        GL20.glLinkProgram(pId);
        GL20.glValidateProgram(pId);

        System.out.println("Shaders initialized");
    }

    public void loop() {

        //BAT
        GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); // Clears the screen color using
        // glClearColor in setupOpenGL()


        GL20.glUseProgram(pId);

        // Bind to the VAO that has all the information about the vertices
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(bat.getVao());
        GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, bat.getVboi());
        System.out.println("Indices buffer bound");

        // Draw the vertices
        GL11.glDrawElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, bat.getIndicesCount(), GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
        System.out.println("Drawing bat with indices");

        // Put everything back to default (deselect)
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
        GL20.glUseProgram(0);

        bat.readInput();

        //CIRCLE
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(ball.getVao());
        GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

        // Draw the vertices

        GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, ball.getCircleVertexSize() / 2);

        // Put everything back to default (deselect)
        GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);

    }

    public int loadShader(String filename, int type) {
        StringBuilder shaderSource = new StringBuilder();
        int shaderID = 0;

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                shaderSource.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not read file.");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        shaderID = GL20.glCreateShader(type);
        GL20.glShaderSource(shaderID, shaderSource);
        GL20.glCompileShader(shaderID);

        return shaderID;
    }


    public void destroyOpenGL() {
        // Delete the shaders
                GL20.glUseProgram(0);
                GL20.glDetachShader(pId, vsId);
                GL20.glDetachShader(pId, fsId);

                GL20.glDeleteShader(vsId);
                GL20.glDeleteShader(fsId);
                GL20.glDeleteProgram(pId);

        GL30.glBindVertexArray(bat.getVao());
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(ball.getVao());

        GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);

        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        GL15.glDeleteBuffers(bat.getVbo());
        GL15.glDeleteBuffers(ball.getVbo());

        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        GL15.glDeleteBuffers(bat.getVboi());

        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        GL15.glDeleteBuffers(bat.getVboc());

        GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
        GL30.glDeleteVertexArrays(bat.getVao());
        //GL30.glDeleteVertexArrays(ball.getVao());
        System.out.println("Everything deleted");
        Display.destroy();
        System.out.println("Display destroyed");
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Test();

    }

}
```

Bat class :

```
package myPackage;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils;
import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30;


public class Bat {

    float x,y,z,w,height,width; 
    float yp = 0;
    private int vao = 0;
    private int vbo = 0;
    private int vboi = 0;
    private int vboc = 0;
    private int indicesCount;
    float[] batVertex ;
    byte[] indices;
    float[] colors;

    public Bat(float x, float y, float z, float w, float width, float height) {

        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
        this.w = w;
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;

         batVertex = new float[]{ // Vertex coordinates

                x, y, z, w,                       // ID = 0
                x + width, y , z, w,              // ID = 1
                x + width, y - height, z, w,      // ID = 2
                x , -y , z , w                    // ID = 3

        };

        FloatBuffer batBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(batVertex.length);
            batBuffer.put(batVertex);
            batBuffer.flip();

        colors = new float[] {
                 1f, 0f, 0f, 1f,
                 0f, 1f, 0f, 1f,
                 0f, 0f, 1f, 1f,
                 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f,
                 };


        FloatBuffer colorsBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(colors.length);
        colorsBuffer.put(colors);
        colorsBuffer.flip();


        //QUAD INDICES
        indices = new byte[] {
            0,3,2,
            2,1,0
        };

        indicesCount = indices.length;
        ByteBuffer indicesBuffer = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(indicesCount);
        indicesBuffer.put(indices);
        indicesBuffer.flip();
        //===============================




        //BAT VBO AND ARRAY
        vao = GL30.glGenVertexArrays();
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(vao);

        vbo = GL15.glGenBuffers();
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
        GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, batBuffer, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL11.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
        //=====================================


        //Colors vbo
        vboc = GL15.glGenBuffers();
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboc);
        GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorsBuffer, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL11.GL_FLOAT, false, 0,0);
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        //======================================

        GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);

        //Indices vbo
        vboi = GL15.glGenBuffers();
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboi);
        GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indicesBuffer, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        //=======================================


        System.out.println("Bat initialized");
    }

    public void moveUp() {

        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, getVbo());


        //System.out.println("x : " + bat.getVertices()[0] + " y : " + bat.getVertices()[1]);

        if (getVertices()[1] >= 1.0f) {

            yp = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i < getVertexSize(); i = i + 4) {
                getVertices()[i] = getVertices()[i] + yp;

            }
        }

        else {
            yp = 0.025f;
            for (int i = 1; i < getVertexSize(); i = i + 4) {
                getVertices()[i] = getVertices()[i] + yp;

            }
        }

        FloatBuffer vertexFloatBuffer = BufferUtils
                .createFloatBuffer(getVertexSize());
        vertexFloatBuffer.put(getVertices());
        vertexFloatBuffer.flip();

        GL15.glBufferSubData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, vertexFloatBuffer);

        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    }

    public void moveDown() {

        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, getVbo());
        //System.out.println("x : " + bat.getVertices()[0] + " y : " + bat.getVertices()[1]);

        if (getVertices()[13] < -1.0f) {
            yp = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i < getVertexSize(); i = i + 4) {
                getVertices()[i] = getVertices()[i] - yp;

            }
        }

        else {
            yp = 0.025f;
            for (int i = 1; i < getVertexSize(); i = i + 4) {
                getVertices()[i] = getVertices()[i] - yp;

            }
        }

        FloatBuffer vertexFloatBuffer = BufferUtils
                .createFloatBuffer(getVertexSize());
        vertexFloatBuffer.put(getVertices());
        vertexFloatBuffer.flip();

        GL15.glBufferSubData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, vertexFloatBuffer);

        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    }

    public void readInput() {

        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_W)) {

            moveUp();
        }

        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_S)) {

            moveDown();
        }

        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_ESCAPE)) {

            System.exit(0);
            Display.destroy();
        }

    }

    public int getVao() {
        return vao;
    }


    public int getVbo() {
        return vbo;
    }

    public int getVboi() {
        return vboi;
    }

    public int getVboc() {
        return vboc;
    }

    public int getVertexSize(){

        return batVertex.length;

    }

    public int getIndicesCount(){
        return indicesCount;
    }

    public float[] getVertices() {

        return batVertex;

    }

    public byte[] getIndices() {
        return indices;
    }



}
```

Ball class :

```
package myPackage;

import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30;

public class Ball {

    float r = 0.03f;
    float x;
    float y;
    float offSetX = 0;
    float offSetY = 0;
    private int vao = 0;
    private int vbo = 0;
    float[] circleVertex ;

    public Ball(float r, float offSetX, float offSetY) {

        this.r = r;

        this.offSetX = offSetX;
        this.offSetY = offSetY;

        int SUBDIVISIONS = 20;

         circleVertex = new float[(SUBDIVISIONS) * 2];

        for (int i = 2; i < circleVertex.length; i = i + 2) {

            double angle = Math.PI * 2 * i / SUBDIVISIONS;

            x = (float) Math.cos(angle) * r;
            y = (float) Math.sin(angle) * r;

            circleVertex[i] = x + offSetX;
            circleVertex[i + 1] = y + offSetY;

        }

        circleVertex[0] = 0 + offSetX;
        circleVertex[1] = 0 + offSetY;

        FloatBuffer circleBuffer = BufferUtils
                .createFloatBuffer(circleVertex.length);
        circleBuffer.put(circleVertex);
        circleBuffer.flip();

        vao = GL30.glGenVertexArrays();
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(vao);

        vbo = GL15.glGenBuffers();
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
        GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, circleBuffer,
                GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL11.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        System.out.println("Ball initialized");
    }

    public int getVao() {
        return vao;
    }

    public int getVbo() {
        return vbo;
    }

    public int getCircleVertexSize() {
        return circleVertex.length;
    }


}
```

Fragment shader :

```
#version 150

in vec4 pass_Color;

out vec4 out_Color;

void main(void) {
    out_Color = pass_Color;
}
```

Vertex shader :

```
#version 150

in vec4 in_Position;
in vec4 in_Color;

out vec4 pass_Color;

void main(void){
    gl_Position = in_Position;
    pass_Color = in_Color;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At around line 88 in the Bat class, before the color buffer definition, you have an extra `GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);`.

Because of that, the color buffer never ends up in the correct array, instead it's linked to nothing.